# grid view with admob rectangle ad not adjusting the width

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I am trying to display admob rectangle ad along with the grid view. The Ad also should scroll along with the list items. But the rectangle ad size is 300 X 250. I am getting the ad in the grid view but ad size is not changed, its showing like a grid item, as per the image i am trying

[image]

in this image admob ad is showing as a separate item but I am getting as below

[image]

and my flutter code is

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              child: GridView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.69,
                ),
                shrinkWrap: false,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: (utilityController.amazonShopModel!.length / 6).ceil() +
                    utilityController.amazonShopModel!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  if (position > 0 && (position + 1) % 7 == 0) {
                    // Show AdMob Ad after every 6 items
                    return _buildAdContainer(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 240.0,);
                  } else {
                    final dataIndex = position-(position ~/ 7); // Adjust index to skip ad positions
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                      child: AmazonShopItems(
                        amazonShopModel:
                        utilityController.amazonShopModel![dataIndex],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            );




 Widget _buildAdContainer({required double width, required double height}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: Center(
          child: AdmobAdUnits.getRectangleBannerAd() == null
              ? Container()
              : Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
            child: Expanded(child: AdWidget(ad: AdmobAdUnits.getRectangleBannerAd()!)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

in addition, I am getting an error as `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.`

Comment: for that you have to create your own native ad.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I solved the issue using StaggeredGridView.countBuilder. its working now as i expected.

Comment: that's great. if you want to change the layout of the ad and make it to look like other children of the grid you have to write that in native code which i have recently implemented in one project using obj-c and java.

Comment: you can use this package to show a Native Ad in Gridview

[ad_gridview](https://pub.dev/packages/ad_gridview)